# Image to spectogram and play

Tags: android

I need to make an app that turns an image into sound. The image is introduced and a spectogram is created to be reproduced.

This is the most difficult exercise I have ever come across.

Can someone give me a tip on how to proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Any tips? Any library that i can help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChristianB I've read a lot about it. the Algorithm is not difficult. The image must be transformed into an xy spectogram (time and frequency) ready for sound reading. The problem is that I have no idea how to turn an image into a spectrum, then playing that spectrum. I'm a little confused

Comment: I have no answer for you, but I bet you are not the first one doing this. Maybe there are some science papers explaining this.

Comment: @ChristianB A lot, yes. I will search again some papers and wait for any help around here. Thank youfor your time ChristianB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're searching something like this:
[How to encode an image in frequency spectrum at python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698549/how-to-encode-an-image-in-frequency-spectrum-at-python)?

Someone provided this [repo](https://github.com/peteshadbolt/spectrogram). It worked for me.

Comment: interesting interesting... I will check this comment as the solution. Great help David. Thank you, Obrigado amigo